# Как обновить окно в C++ ncurses?

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses

Конда пытаюсь нажать KEY_UP или KEY_DOWN, мой текст не изменяется. Я пробовал и очищать окно через `wclear()` и `wrefresh()` - безрезультатно. Язык - C++, система - Linux, работаю с ncurses. Код: https://termbin.com/g0t7. Так как обновить содержимое окна??

UPD: ещё и на Enter не реагирует, хмм

UPD2: поменял `getch()` на `wgetch()` - бесполезно, не реагирует

UPD3: Заменил `if-else` на `switch-case` и пробовал ещё закрывать программу на `getch() = ERR`. Не работает.

UPD4: "Вывел" окно из цикла `while True`. Теперь getch работает, но мне надо обновлять окно по нажатию кнопок. Пробовал `goto`, но он не работает... Новый код: https://termbin.com/6ias

Comment: как минимум, чтобы `wgetch()` возвращал коды клавиш вроде `KEY_UP`, окно curses должно находится в keypad-режиме (добавь `keypad(stdscr, true)` в `main()`)... остальную логику я не смотрел... ЗЫ: код лучше добавлять прямо в вопрос...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Fat-Zer за `keypad(true)`. Но само решение я подглядел здесь: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YiPdibiQHA. А общем, надо делать `wrefresh()` сразу по созданию окна через `box()`. Только потом можно обновлять это окно как хочешь.